# Computing difficult expectation

Tags: distributions, expected-value, moments

I am doing some derivations for a project and at some point the following integral shows up

$$ \int x^{c} \log(1-F(x)) N f(x) [1-F(x)]^{N-1} dx  $$

i.e the expectation of the product of natural logarithm of survivor function (or the ccdf) and the random variable $x$ integrated using the distribution of the minimum of $N$ independent draws of some random variable $y$ with probability distribution $F(y)$. $c$ is a non-random constant.

This has the flavor of a Shannon entropy or something like that. One way to think about this is as the expectation of $x^{c}\log(1-F(x))$ where $x = \min \left\{y_{1},\dots,y_{N}\right\}$ under the distribution of $x$.

I was wondering whether you can think of some sort of simplification or way to solve or simplify this integral. Of course, once one assumes a particular distribution $F(\cdot)$ it becomes easy, but I would like to simplify this as much as possible in terms of known moments (means, variances, etc) as much as possible in order to have a general expression.

Note: one interesting thing is that the definite integral of this expression when one does not multiply by the $x^{c}$,

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \log(1-F(x)) N f(x) [1-F(x)]^{N-1} dx = -\frac{1}{N}  $$

I tried to build on this and use integration by parts to try to solve the integral above but did not work.

Comment: Because the relationship between $x$ and $f(x)$ is as arbitrary as it possibly could be, I expect there to be no simplification in general.